# how do i compare each character of a same string using a for loop?

Tags: java

So I have to make a program where I have to compare each character of a string to see if they occur in the string more than once or not, if they occur more than once then I have to delete that string from an array list for instance "peer" and "pear" then it should remove "peer" because there are 2 e's in "peer", so how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. To check whether there is any duplicate character you can use a `Set`.

```
For each character of String
    check if the char is in the set
    if yes
         then you can delete this String from arraylist and stop checking this string
    else
         add this char to the set
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `if(Pattern.matches("\w{2,}",ID)==true){//do what you want}`. Then I wish you know how to remove the string.

Comment: This is not valid Java syntax

Comment: i kinda fixed it

Answer (score 0):

## Pythonic answer:

```
charlist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','p','r']
stringlist=['peer','pear']
for string in stringlist:
  for character in charlist:
    if string.count(character) > 1:
      stringlist.remove(string)
print (stringlist)
```